# How do I make a 1D shadow map from an Occlusion Map? Mine becomes white

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, fbo, post-processing

I'v been working for some Time now in GPU post processing effects for my game, but I'v come to an issue that seems unsolvable, trying to achieve a Top-Down directional light.

I have generated an occlude map from the scene, and I am trying to create a height map with this shader inspired from the pixel perfect shadows tutorial for libgdx:

```
varying vec2 vTexCoord0;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 ts; // the occlusion texture size

void main(void) {
    float dst = 1.0;
    for (float y=0.0; y<ts.y; y+=1.0) {
        float d = y/ts.y;
        vec2 coord = vec2(vTexCoord0.x, dst);
        vec4 data = texture2D(u_texture, coord);

        if (data.r > 0.0) {
            dst = min(dst, d);
        }
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(dst);
}
```

the input texture is like a sinus wave with a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 100% of the texture. (i cannot post a pic yet, I need more reputation) but the texture is opaque over the sine wave(if not flipped after the FBO rendered)and transparent where there is air.

the java render code is this one:

```
public void MakeShadowMap() {

        cam2.setToOrtho(false, shadowMapFBO.getWidth(), shadowMapFBO.getHeight());
        //cam2.position.set(Vector3.Zero);
        cam2.update();

        shadowMapShader.setUniformf("ts", Alpha.getWidth(),Alpha.getHeight());

        shadowMapFBO.begin();

        Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
        Gdx.gl20.glBlendFuncSeparate(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam2.combined);
        batch.setShader(shadowMapShader);
        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(Alpha.getColorBufferTexture(),0,0, shadowMapFBO.getWidth(), shadowMapFBO.getHeight()); // Alpha is the Occlusion FBO

        batch.end();

        shadowMapFBO.end();
        Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
        Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    }
```

But with this shader, it generates A 1D shadow map that is completely white, as if there was nothing on the Occlusion map. I'v tried flipping the Occlusion map, I'v looked in the error log of the shader, and it is theoretically fine.

What did I do wrong? Is there an alternative way to generate a 1D shadow Map?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that the uniform was not set because I forgot to call begin and end before and after.

```
shadowMapShader.begin();
shadowMapShader.setUniformf("ts", Alpha.getWidth(),Alpha.getHeight());
shadowMapShader.end();
```